# change numeric to date sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table where date is stored as numeric values. Example:

```
localdate

20150109112542 
20150109113643 
20150109130244 
20150109163900 
20150109164127
```

To convert I am using this piece of code:

```
SELECT
convert(datetime,convert(varchar(8),LocalDate,113)) from book1
```

but I get a result like this:

```
Column1

09/01/2015 00:00:00 
09/01/2015 00:00:00 
09/01/2015 00:00:00 
09/01/2015 00:00:00 
09/01/2015 00:00:00
```

Seems only captures date, but not time. Any ideas?

Edit:

I did try to change to bigger varchar (like 14), but I got this error: `Error 241: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this using `STUFF()` and `CONVERT()` functions with *style* 112:
[**Fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/1620)

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 
    STUFF(STUFF(
      STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), localDate), 9, 0, ' '), 12, 0,':'), 15, 0,':'), 112)
FROM book1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `varchar()` big enough to fit all the characters:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, convert(varchar(14), LocalDate,113))
from book1;
```

Comment: I did try, but for everything different than varchar(8) I got this error: Error 241: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.